# Hide TinyMCE content until editor is initialized

Tags: asp.net, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE in an asp.net app, and setting the content of the textareas on the server.  The problem is, as soon as the page loads, we see the raw HTML in the textareas for a brief moment until the editors are initialized.  I've tried setting display:none on the textareas, then calling .next().show() on each text area in the oninit routine, which works, except the editors are not the size they need to be (probably because the underlying textarea was hidden when the editors were initialized?)

How have others solved this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could save the textarea content, then set it empty and reset the tinymce content after the editor got initialized:

```
var content = $('textarea_id').html();
$('textarea_id').html('');

tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   setup : function(ed) {
    ed.onInit.add(function(ed, evt) {
           ed.setContent(content);
        });
   },
   ...

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this question and decided to leave my solution as follows:

```
//Before loading, hide textarea element using visibility='hidden' so that the space the element takes will be maintained
document.querySelector('.editor').style.visibility = 'hidden';

tinyMCE.init({
    editor_selector: "editor",
    setup: function (ed) {
        ed.onInit.add(function (ed, evt) {
            //show the element again now that the editor is loaded.
            document.querySelector('.editor').style.visibility = 'visible';
        });
    }
});
```